# creating new thread in an event

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, kinect

I have created a thread within event sensor_DepthFrameReady but when I execute it throw 
an exception on line 8(Depths[depth]++;) in the function SetImage1Frame and throw this exception:

Index was outside the bounds of the array.(depth = -1)

what is going wrong? I think that the function (SetImage1Frame ) is executing more than one time ,but I used this function only in this method(sensor_DepthFrameReady)!!

```
    void sensor_DepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        short[] pixels;
        Thread th;
        using (frame=e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
        {
            if (frame!=null)
            {
                pixels = new short[frame.PixelDataLength];
                frame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixels);
                th = new Thread(() =>
                    SetImage1Frame(pixels));
                th.Start();
            }
        }     

    }
    int[] Depths=new int[4096];
    int depth=0;
    double chartBarWidth;
    void SetImage1Frame(short[] dpixels)
    {
        int maxValue = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dpixels.Length; i++)
        {
            depth = dpixels[i] >> DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth;
            if (depth > 0)
            {
                Depths[depth]++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Depths.Length; i++)
        {
            maxValue=Math.Max(maxValue,Depths[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Depths.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Depths[i] > 0)
            {
                stackPanel1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                    stackPanel1.Children.Add(r);
                }));
            }
        }
        image1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            WrbitmapImage.WritePixels(rect, dpixels, stride, 0);
        }));

    }
```

Comment: have you stepped through the debugger and looked at the statement when it breaks?

Comment: As an aside, creating a thread on each depth frame is not such a great idea. It is likely to be very slow, and you will be unlikely to be able to spin up 30 new threads every second. If you're creating threads slower than the data comes in, you will eventually run out of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not handling the signed numbers coming in from Kinect correctly. This program demonstrates the problem:-

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        short s = unchecked((short)0x8001);
        int i = s >> 3;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

This program will print -4096. The Kinect input is coming to you as an array of short, which is a signed type. When you shift away the player index, that number is being sign extended and remaining a negative number. In your case, since you're seeing -1, that is probably a pixel in the depth view which is at more than 4 metres away. To fix the problem, you should cast the depth pixel value to ushort before dealing with it and use only unsigned types.